# Creating a Vertical Carousel with no easing effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've tried different vertical carousels and jquery Cycle appears to be the only solution that works across all browsers. I'm wanting to create a vertical carousel that does not pause at the end of each transition. The documentation for jquery Cycle is not that extensive. How would I set the carousel so that there is no transition at the end. I've tried most possible without it working.

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Xxahy/24/

JS code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cycle-streams').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollVert',
    continuous: 1,
    speed: 3000,
    delay: 0,
    easing: 0
  });
});​
```

HTML code...

```
<div class="cycle-streams">
   <div class="item">
     <div class="span12">
       stream 1
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 2
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 3
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 4
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 5
     </div>
   </div>                        
   <div class="item">
     <div class="span12">
       stream 6
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 7
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 8
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 9
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
       stream 10
     </div>
   </div>                    
     <div class="item">
       <div class="span12">
         stream 11
       </div>
       <div class="span12">
         stream 12
       </div>
       <div class="span12">
         stream 13
       </div>
       <div class="span12">
         stream 14
       </div>
       <div class="span12">
         stream 15
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cycle-streams').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollVert',
        continuous: 1,
        speed: 3000,
        delay: 0,
        easing: 'linear' // this is the correct setting
    });
});​
```

Comment: So easing is similar to that of CSS transition?

Comment: In the sense that they are named presets, yes. I also believe you can define an easing function, but I'm not sure.